# Having issues with highlighting text on button press - chrome extension

Tags: javascript, highlight, sendmessage, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am working on a Google Chrome Extension that will have a feature to highlight specific words. I have been able to get the extension to highlight words within the `popup` window. However, when I try to modify my code and highlight words from the `Active Tab` I run into issues. I am trying to use `chrome.tabs.sendMessage` to perform the action. The message never hits the `listener` that I have in place. Maybe I have it in the wrong file?

**popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="button.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
    <script src="selection.js"></script>
    <script src="hilitor.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <button id="highlightText">Scan for Washington</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse){
    if (request.message == "getSelection"){
       console.log("Inside Get Selection");
       var myHilitor = new Hilitor("content"); // id of the element to parse
       myHilitor.apply("washington state one");
       console.log(request, sender, sendResponse);
    }
    sendResponse();
});
```

**popup.js**

```
$(function(){
    $('#highlightText').click(function(){highlightAllText();});
});

function highlightAllText() {
    console.log("Inside Highlight All Text");

    chrome.windows.getCurrent(w => {
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, windowId: w.id}, tabs => {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {
                "message": "getSelection"
            });
        });
    });
```

I am currently using [Washington Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Washington_(state)) as my page to highlight. I am also using the [Hilitor Library](https://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/search-highlight/) to perform the highlighting at this moment. Again, I can highlight everything in the `popup` window that is created from `popup.html`, but I can't highlight outside of that.

Answer (score 0):

So I have finally figured out how to accomplish my task. The send message/listeners were in the wrong location. This is the new `popup.js` file:

**popup.js**

```
function popup() {
    chrome.tabs.query({
        currentWindow: true,
        active: true
    }, function(tabs) {
        var activeTab = tabs[0];
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeTab.id, {
            message: "start",
            tabID: tabs[0].id,
            tabURL: tabs[0].url
        });
    });
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    document.getElementById("highlightText").addEventListener("click", popup);
});
```

I had to do some refactoring/tutorial watching/beating my head against the wall, but this is the new `content script` that I am using to highlight:

**contentScript.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.message === "start") {

            console.log("Before Hilitor");

            var myHilitor = new Hilitor("content"); // id of the element to parse
            myHilitor.apply("washington state one");
            console.log("After Hilitor");
        }
    }
);
```

This is my `popup.html` page:

**popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!--    <link rel="stylesheet" href="button.css">-->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
    <script src="contentScript.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<button id="highlightText">Scan for Washington</button>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is what my `manifest.json` file looks like

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Hello World",
  "description": "Hello World",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "permissions": ["storage", "activeTab", "scripting", "tabs"],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "/images/get_started16.png",
      "32": "/images/get_started32.png",
      "48": "/images/get_started48.png",
      "128": "/images/get_started128.png"
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "/images/get_started16.png",
    "32": "/images/get_started32.png",
    "48": "/images/get_started48.png",
    "128": "/images/get_started128.png"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "js": ["contentScript.js", "hilitor.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```